# changing style of the active element on a WP PHP Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a menu using this function:

```
function nav_menu( $theme_location ) {
    if ( ($theme_location) && ($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$theme_location]) ) {
        $menu = get_term( $locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        $menu_list  = '<nav class="titlemenu">' ."\n";
            $menu_list  .= '<ul class="navbar-nav" id="menu-top">' ."\n";
            foreach( $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                $menu_list .= '<li class="nav-item">' ."\n";
                $menu_list .= '<a href="' . $menu_item->url . '" class="nav-link">' . strtoupper($menu_item->title) . '</a>' ."\n";
                $menu_list .= '</li>' ."\n";
            }
            $menu_list .= '</ul>' ."\n";
        $menu_list .= '</nav>' ."\n";
    } else {
        $menu_list = '<!-- no menu defined in location "'.$theme_location.'" -->';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
}
```

the problem is I want to highlight the current page I am on the menu but it seems not possible due when I apply a pseudoclass it applies to all the menu elements, maybe with a JS function or similar will be able to achieve that?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? I don't believe WordPress stores menu item data using individual nav_menu_item WP Post entries anymore.

Comment: thanks for your reply @kofeigen, I'll have a look. I'm afraid that means there is no way to achieve it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just adding a JS to add a class and it works:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link").forEach((link) => {
    if (link.href === window.location.href) {
        link.classList.add("active");
        link.setAttribute("aria-current", "page");
    }
});
```

then add the class "active" in the css

Comment: Interesting solution. Just keep in mind it might break if you upgrade WordPress to a newer version. Please mark your own answer as **accepted** if it works. It will be helpful to those who find your question in search results to know a correct answer is available. Thanks.